# Cleaning Time Series Outliers without removing data in Python

Tags: python, time-series, data-cleaning, outliers

I am looking for the (or a similar) function in Python: (clean.boudt)

Page 94-95:
https://cran.r-project.org/web//packages/PerformanceAnalytics/PerformanceAnalytics.pdf

The procedure looks like this:
[image]
[image]

Is there a package in Python which performs this calculation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). Load the data into a dataframe and you can get all the distribution data (mean, quantiles, covariance, etc) you need performantly. Then apply a lambda function based on your array and filter out items that don't meet the criteria. It will take some messing around with but you'll be able to get it working.

I did some googling with keywords "pandas multivariate winsorization outliers" and found [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/detecting-and-treating-outliers-in-python-part-3-dcb54abaf7b0). It think it shows you how to do it right out of the gate. Good luck and get her done!